# what is setShooter in sequelize transaction?

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

what will user.setShooter will do here?

```
return sequelize.transaction(function (t) {

  // chain all your queries here. make sure you return them. <br>
  return User.create({<br>
    firstName: 'Abraham',<br>
    lastName: 'Lincoln'<br>
  }, {transaction: t}).then(function (user) {<br>
    return user.setShooter({<br>
      firstName: 'John',<br>
      lastName: 'Boothe'<br>
    }, {transaction: t});<br>
  });<br>
<br>
}).then(function (result) {<br>
  // Transaction has been committed<br>
  // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback<br>
}).catch(function (err) {<br>
  // Transaction has been rolled back<br>
  // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback<br>
});<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

setShooter is nothing more than a function in the certain Sequelize model class

e.g.

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

export default class Product extends Sequelize.Model {

    // model init
    static init(sequelize) {
        return super.init({
                name: { type: Sequelize.STRING(128), allowNull: false },
                description: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: false }
            },
            {
                sequelize,
                tableName: 'c_products'
            })
    }

    setShooter() {
        console.log('Hello World!')
    }

}
```

Comment: So it's actually just a custom method defined in a Sequelize model?